Using sed to delete quoted words within a quoted string
I have a JSON file with 1000s of lines as follows:
"title": "Revert "Merge branch \"mq-fw-v3\" into dev""

The thing that remains constant is "title:" (with the quotes). And towards the end there is the into word. So basically title is the key, and all after colon ( : ) is the value. I want to basically delete the part "Merge branch "mq-fw-v3" into dev", along with the quotes. In other words I want to delete the value.
I tried doing with sed, but have not been able to. NOTE that there are also lines such as:
"title": "Merge branch "git-ci-cd" into stage"

which has only 1 quoted string, git-ci-cd in this case, inside the outer quoted string which in this case is "Merge branch "git-ci-cd" into stage". I want to delete these too. Just the value part.
Any ideas?
EDIT
I am trying the following regex:
sed -e 's#Merge branch \"[[:print:]]\{3,\}\" into [[:print:]]\{0,\}\"##g'

But then there is an exceptional case that has surfaced:
"title": "Merge branch "stage" of https://gitlab.phonepe.com/om/backend/hermes into stage"

I guess its the front-slash that is not being covered. Any idea how to cover it too?

Neither of your examples here are valid JSON data. The first one would look something like {"title": "Revert \"Merge branch \"mq-fw-v3\" into dev\""} (note that all the inner quotes are escaped). Either you need to fix the data in your question, if it was a typo, or we can't help you, because you have a tool that is generating invalid data and you need to fix the tool.

Also, could you show us an example of your desired output? It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. You say, "In other words I want to delete the value"; does that mean you expect the final result to be "title": ""?

Regular expressions are very poor at restricting matches to "inside" something else. And if you want to automate processing of JSON, it's best to use something specialized to it such as jq.
